# Инициализировать переменные в __main__ аналогично setattr

Tags: python

Есть файл конфигурации `conf.py`, в котором объявляются различные переменные. Если какая-то из них не задана, то конфигурируемое приложение использует значение по умолчанию.

```
a = 'value a'
b = 'value b'
# будет использовано значение по умолчанию
# c = 'value c'
```

У меня десятки таких конфигов, вручную редактировать их неудобно.
Вместо этого я генерирую конфиги с нужными данными, сериализую их в YAML и загружаю в конфиге в словарь:

```
with io.open(conf_path, encoding='utf-8') as fp:
    config = yaml.safe_load(fp)
```

Теперь нужно как-то инициализировать переменные.
Пока что у меня есть только такое решение и оно мне не нравится:

```
# костыль
if 'a' in source:
    a = source['a']

if 'b' in source:
    b = source['b']
...
```

Если бы у меня был класс, то сгодился бы метод [`setattr`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr).
Но в моем случае `__name__ == '__main__'`, а `self` не определено.

```
for name, value in source.items():
    # Это не сработает
    setattr(self, name, value)
```

Что делать? Можно ли что-то передать в `setattr` в качестве `self` или есть ли какой-то другой метод?

Comment: В locals/globals можно записать

Comment: Есть библиотека, называется imp - я бы ее попробовал https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924700/best-way-to-retrieve-variable-values-from-a-text-file-python-json

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич, судя по ответу по приведенной ссылке, данные грузятся в переменную (`data = imp.load_source('data', '', f)`, а потом идет обращение через `data.var1` и т.д.) В данном вопросе уже используется модуль для загрузки из формата yaml, поэтому `imp` тут ни к чему. Здесь действительно нужно будет менять `globals()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Чтобы обратиться к глобальным переменным, как к словарю, есть встроенная функция `globals()`. В вашем случае просто после загрузки конфига нужно сделать `update()` этого словаря:

```
with io.open(conf_path, encoding='utf-8') as fp:
    config = yaml.safe_load(fp)

globals().update(config)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys
module = sys.modules[__name__]
setattr(module, 'name', 'value')
print(name)  # 'value'
```